# jquery ajax POST without form elements

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to post data and the url is simply "v1/wave" and it takes five params. I tried this, but it doesn't work so far:

```
function request(minLat, minLon, maxLat, maxLon, maxNrOfResults, callback){

$.ajax({

        url: 'v1/wave?minLat='+minLat+'&minLong='+minLon+'&maxLat='+maxLat+'&maxLong='+maxLong'+&maxNrOfResults='+maxNrOfResults,
        type: "GET",
        success: function (data) {
            callback(data);
            if(data.msgCode == LOGIN_SUCCESS){
                console.log("request success");



            } else if(data.msgCode == LOGIN_FAILED){
                console.log("request failed");
            }
        },
        error: function(data) {
            handleRequestError(data);
        }
    })
```

ERROR: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string in the url line.

Comment: Can you use Fiddler, to see what the full URL is? it could have some illegal characters in it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should avoid sending the parameters in the url. You should use the `data` property. There are several advantages, including encoding .. or typos :)

```
function request(minLat, minLon, maxLat, maxLon, maxNrOfResults, callback){    
$.ajax({
            url: 'v1/wave',
            data: { minLat : minLat, minLong : minLong, maxLat : maxLat, maxLong : maxLong,  maxNrOfResults : maxNrOfResults },
            type: "POST",
            success: function (data) {
                callback(data);
                if(data.msgCode == LOGIN_SUCCESS){
                    console.log("request success");   
                } else if(data.msgCode == LOGIN_FAILED){
                    console.log("request failed");
                }
            },
            error: function(data) {
                handleRequestError(data);
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo here: `'&maxLong='+maxLong'+`

Comment: it actually worked after fixing this, but I still prefer the way Gabriel mentioned!

Answer (score 1):

Try below

If you want to post the data you can move your data from query string to post data for more secure. Also use ajax type **POST**

```
var myPostData=JSON.stringify({'minLat':minLat,'minLong':minLon, etc});

$.ajax({

    url: 'v1/wave',

    type: "POST",
    data:myPostData,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        callback(data);
        if(data.msgCode == LOGIN_SUCCESS){
            console.log("request success");



        } else if(data.msgCode == LOGIN_FAILED){
            console.log("request failed");
        }
    },
    error: function(data) {
        handleRequestError(data);
    }
})
```